# How to understand conditional expressions in the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql

I encountered a query as so:

```
SELECT
   (period_of >= '2022-05-01') + (period_of >= '2022-06-01') + (period_of >= '2022-07-01') + (period_of >= '2022-08-01') -1 as 'bucket',
    MAX(period_of) as max_dt, MIN(period_of) as min_dt
FROM table_a
WHERE project_id = 123
GROUP BY bucket
```

I don't understand this part of the SELECT statement:
`(period_of >= '2022-05-01') + (period_of >= '2022-06-01') + (period_of >= '2022-07-01') + (period_of >= '2022-08-01') -1 as 'bucket'`

Where can I find ref to this syntax style for the SELECT component?

How can I understand this kind of query?

Comment: It's just a `SELECT` statement. What do you mean by "this type", what's special about it?

Comment: The thing to remember is that the value of conditional expressions is 1 for true, 0 for false. So it's adding up the number of conditions that are true, and using that as the grouping. Basically, it's grouping by the number of months since April to `period_of`

Comment: @Barmar I updated my question to clarify which part of the SELECT statement I don't understand. If there are entries that is true for (period_of >= '2022-05-01') then it shows up on the row where 'bucket' is 0. And if there are entries that fits (period_of >= '2022-06-01') results are displayed under bucket 1. I am looking for a ref to understand this syntax.

Comment: just look up a reference to group by

Comment: @DCR I mostly understand 'group by' but not sure how the group_by works in conjunction with the `(period_of >= '2022-05-01') + ... as 'bucket'` part of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value of a conditional expression is 1 if the condition is true, 0 if the condition is true. So

```
(period_of >= '2022-05-01')
```

will be either 1 or 0 depending on how `period_of` compares to that date.

For instance, if `period_of = 2022-07-15`, it will add `1` for `2022-05-01`, `2022-06-01` and `2022-0701`, and `0` for `2022-08-01`, so `bucket` will be `3`. But if `period_05 = 2022-05-20` it will only add `1` for `2022-05-01`, and `0` for the rest, so `bucket` will be `1`. If `period_of` is before `2022-05-01` `bucket` will be `0`.

So that expression is adding up how many of the 4 dates the `period_of` date is greater than or equal to. Then this total is used for grouping all the results.

This is equivalent to `GROUP BY YEAR(period_of), MONTH(period_of)`, except that everything before May 2022 is grouped together in bucket 0 instead of separate buckets for each month.